# React Router v6: Accessing global state in Loader functions

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am giving react-router v6 a try and I feel like I am missing an important concept when it comes to router `loader`s. For example, in the `react-router` [tutorial where it talks about the `loader` for the `/contacts/:contactId` route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#loading-data), I get that you can easily access any state that is contained in the URL, like the `contactId` in this case. However, I find that in addition to the route parameters I also need things like a `userId` which normally I would have available through a prop or a context provider since I like to keep auth information more global. So I'm having a hard time seeing how to access global state like that inside of the `loader` function.

To get more specific, my `index.js` file is set up like this, where I initialize the `router` object and then pass it to the `root.render()` function:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/user-specific-resources",
        element: <UserResources />,
        loader: resourceLoader,
      },
  }
]);


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

However, the `resourceLoader` function for the `/user-specific-resources` route needs to know the userId/token to pass to the server. I know I could pass the userId as a route parameter like `/user-specific-resources/:userId`, but that feels a little awkward because the `userId` is pretty long. I know I could create some sort of globally-accessible object that contains the user state and pass that to a factory function that returns the user-aware loader, e.g. `loader: resourceLoaderFactory(userStateManager)`. But for some reason to me that seems to run contrary to the ethos of `react-router` v6. So I know there are ways to make this happen, but I love that `react-router` has such nice separation of concerns when it comes to route-specific logic and the solutions I have thought of feel a little awkward. So really my question is, does `react-router` v6 have a more elegant way of handling this sort of thing which I missed when reading the documentation, or is this just the messiness that always comes when you leave the toy problem that was used in the tutorial and start writing more "real world" code?

Comment: What sort of "global state/context" are you needing to access? Depending on what you need to access, and how it can be accessed, changes the solution. Can you include a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

This issues is discussed here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9324

Here is my temporary solution to this problem. You can wrap RouterProvider and routes creation with a custom one that uses hooks.

```
const CustomRouterProvider = () => {
 const {userId, setUserId}= useState(); // or get it from context/custom hook

 const router = createBrowserRouter([
   {
     path: "/",
     element: <UserResources/>,
     loader: async () => {
           resourceLoader(userId);
         },
   },
 ]);

 return (
   <RouterProvider router={router} />
 );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <CustomRouterProvider />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: I'n not sure about the overhead, but it does work to import react context data in the router loaders.